# Identities when deriving the Forward Kolmogorov

Tags: calculus, probability, ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Given the Ito diffusion

$$
dX(t)= \mu dt + \sigma dW(t)
$$

And a function $F(X(t),t)$, then by Ito Lemma

$$
dF = \left(\mu \frac{ \partial F }{ \partial x } + \frac{ \sigma^2 }{2} \frac{\partial^2 F }{\partial x^2} \right) dt + \sigma  \frac{\partial F}{\partial x} dW
$$

(Leaving out the arguments for simplicity)

Then the density $p(x,t)$ of the function $F(X(t),t)$ is obtained from the Forward Kolmogorov equation

$$
\frac{\partial p(x,t)}{\partial t} = - \frac{\partial  (\mu p(x,t))}{\partial x} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 (\sigma^2 p(x,t))}{\partial x^2} 
$$

Now to derive the FK, I take the derivative of the expectation and perform a series of integration by parts. During this step I end up with a bunch of integrals which I set to zero.

Are the following equalities/identities true? If so why?

(1) 
$$
p(x,t) \mu F \left. \right|_{\infty }^{-\infty}=0
$$

(2)
$$
p(x,t) \intop\nolimits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sigma^2}{2}\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x^2} dx =0
$$

(3)
$$
p(x,t) \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 (\sigma^2 p(x,t))}{\partial x^2} F \left. \right|_{-\infty }^{\infty}=0
$$

Thank you in advance!

Notes: I understand that when time goes to infinity, the probability density and the derivatives converge to zero - but I still do not understand why integrating over the state space should also equal to zero. Please leave a comment if I should write out the whole derivation.

Comment: Are $\sigma$ and $\mu$ just constants...? Or do you actually consider the SDE $$dX_t = \mu(X_t) \, dt + \sigma(X_t) \, dW_t$$ ....?

Comment: @saz Yes, the drift and diffusion can be constants or functions of $X$ and $t$. Both cases are treated the same in the books I have looked at.